# event handler that uses 'this' keyword not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Title may not be correct but i didnt know how to ask my question !
I have encountered a problem with `this` keyword . While using it as in this code `<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></input>`
it works perfectly. But when i allot a function on input element that uses `this` keyword , it dont work as in
HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="up();"></input>
```

Javascript

```
function up()
{   
    this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to extend DOM elements prototype with function:**

```js
HTMLInputElement.prototype.up = function() {
    if(this.type == "text") {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="up();" placeholder="type something" />
```

**but I strictly recommend You to use jquery for this, because I don't think that HTMLInputElement will always persist on all browsers:**

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('input.to-uppercase')
    .on('keyup', function(){$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="to-uppercase" placeholder="write something">
```

Comment: Sorry, it will work. It's just a bad idea to extend the `HTMLInputElement` prototype in this way.

Comment: yeah it works , but i am not getting how it works , i am new to javascript . can u please explain your code @num8er

Comment: @torazaburo, I know about it, I've updated my answer. (:

Comment: @johnscott every DOM object has it's set of functions, and it can be accessible and extendible through prototype. so, I've added to it's behavior up() function. that's all. but again, use jQuery realization, because it's safer than using HTMLInputElement.
Also read about OOP part of JavaScript. It will be really helpful in future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: I actually preferred your first solution better. But in any case, it's standard do just do `onkeyup="up(this")` and `function up(elt)`.

Comment: I don't like to bind events to elements html code, always use javascript frameworks and place them in js file. For me it's cleaner to keep js, css part in separated files

Answer (score 8):

**this** here will not be the element, you need to pass this from the DOM, use it like this

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="up(this);"></input>
```

your function

```
function up(el)
{   
    el.value=el.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the probably most horrible thing JavaScript offers:

```
onclick="up.call(this);"
```

`call(...)` basically sets the `this` inside a function to a specific value, in this case to the element.